# How to make next/prev links by increment?

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I want to have next link on my page for viewing next episodes. I want to do it by increments.  I have this but does not work.

```
<p><a id="asdf" href="sample-1">Next</a> 
<script>
document.getElementById('asdf').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var n = e.target.href.split('-')[1] * 1 + 1;
if (n > 4)
n = 1;
e.target.href = e.target.href.split('-')[0] + '-' + n + ".php";
}, false);
</script>
<div class="div3">
<ul>
<li><a href="sample-1.php">Anohana Ep1</a></li>
<li><a href="sample-2.php">Anohana Ep2</a></li>
<li><a href="sample-3.php">Anohana Ep3</a></li>      
</ul>
</div>
```

Should I determine first the file name of current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parseInt` to convert to number:

```
document.getElementById('asdf').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var n = parseInt(e.target.href.split('-')[1]) + 1;
    if (n > 4) n = 1;    
    e.target.href = e.target.href.split('-')[0] + '-' + n + ".php";
}, false);
```

**Explanation**. The problem with your code is that after the first click `href` turns into `sample-1.php`. Which when split produces an array `['sample', '1.php']`. When you then try to convert `1.php` to number with multiplication operator `*` it returns `NaN` of course. So you should use `parseInt` in this case which will extract numeric part properly.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1jworgLu/

Comment: thanks for the fast answer.. i was on sample-1 then clicked next it woked. but then im on sample-2 clicked next its still on the same page?. I add this script will on every page right? on sample-1, sample-2 ...

Comment: Probably because of `e.preventDefault();` which I added for testing purposes?

Comment: I still don't get it. T^T  I did not included e.preventDefault();. but still when im in sample-2 it keeps on going sample-2.. Is it because of the href="sample-1" on every page?

Comment: Yes, probably. You should have sample-1, sample-2, etc. on different pages respectively.

Comment: in my sample-1 i have <a id="asdf" href="sample-1">Next</a>  then in sample-2 i should put <a id="asdf" href="sample-2">Next</a> to make it go to sample-3? and so on? then i have to edit a lot of pages..i think i should determine or get the file name of the current page and start increment there?/